# MacBook Air headphone jack causing mac to go into sleep mode

Tags: sleep-wake, headphones, logicboard

So my MacBook Air continuously flickers between on and sleep modes. It stays on only when I plug in the headphone jack and keep it at an angle pressed. I took it to the store and I was told it could be that the logic board is shorting.

I would like to know if someone had this issue before and if it's an easy fix by opening the laptop. Also, my laptop is not under warranty.

Comment: Without knowing the specific model of your Macbook Air, it's next to impossible to even give you a general diagnosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the MacBook Air has a MagSafe DC In board that also has an audio connector.

[image]

It's very conceivable that there is a broken connection on this board that "fixes" itself when you put pressure on the headphone jack.  Technically you could fix this, but it's probably simpler to just change this board out.

If you provide me with your specific make and model, I will provide you with a more accurate PN# and a link to the repair documents.

Comment: The model is Mac Air 13" - 2013. I suspect that the jack has a loose connection or is shorting a trace on the logic board causing it to flicker between the on and sleep modes. It would also be great if you could direct me to resources where I could buy the logic board and replace it myself.

Comment: I also see a Macbook I/O replacement tutorial on a website but I'm not entirely sure that will fix it.

Comment: They sell this on [Amazon](https://goo.gl/qm7Zyg).  I have fixed may MacBooks with power issues using these replacement boards so you shouldn't have any trouble.

Comment: Why wouldn't it fix it?  That part is exactly where the power and the audio jack intersect and is separate from the logic board.

Comment: Why does it put the system into sleep-mode though? I have no idea but this board seems like the issue. Could you also give me the version number for a MacAir 13" 2013 model?

Comment: What happens if you momentarily push the power button while the Mac is on?  It goes to sleep.  PN#820-3455-A

Comment: I got myself a screw driver and opened it up. Got all the connections to the I/O board out, dusted the board a little and added insulation tape around the headphone port. I plugged it back in and it work just fine now. I'm guessing the jack on the board got slightly loose with abusive use. Thanks for the help Allan!